# What is the best way to show icon/button only when hover on an object ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a cover-image like this

[image]

When the user hover on my image, I want to :

- show an camera icon on the top left, and
- hide it back when the mouse move away.

  ---

## I have tried

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">

    #cover-img:hover{
        opacity: .9;
    }

    #nav-upload-icon{
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        color: red;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

</style>
```

HTML

```
<img id="cover-img" src="/material/img/profile-menu.png" height="130px">
<i id="nav-upload-icon" class="md md-camera hidden"></i>
```

JS

```
$("#cover-img").hover(function() {
   $("#nav-upload-icon").removeClass( "hidden" );
});
```

I couldn't get it to behave what I expected to see. 
What is the best way to implement something like that ?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/pdj5xuj6/)

Comment: Thank-you guys so much for helping me on this post. You guys are awesome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reason to use JavaScript if that is the actual html code, you can use the next sibling selector with hover.

```
#cover-img:hover + #nav-upload-icon,  
#nav-upload-icon:hover {
    visibility: visible;
}

#nav-upload-icon { 
    visibility : hidden; 
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, the + this is better than my solution.

Comment: Ohh nice. Look I can achieve this in CSS. Smart. :)

Comment: @epascarello, I was going to vote up but I tried it in  http://jsfiddle.net/pdj5xuj6/8/ and its not working. Am I missing something stupid?

Comment: Hmm... you're right. According to the link, I'm not sure it not working as well.

Comment: Because you have the hidden class on the element which is setting display and not visibility. Remove that class.

Comment: @epascarello, knew it would be something like that. Thanks for point out

Comment: Actually it needs a slight change, updated my code to add one more hover, without it, the item would flicker.

Comment: Was about to ask you about that, but seem like you're pretty quick. :)

Answer (score 2):

bind mouseout event to remove add the `hidden` class again

```
$("#cover-img").hover(function() {
    $("#nav-upload-icon").removeClass("hidden");
});
$("#cover-img").mouseout(function() {
    $("#nav-upload-icon").addClass("hidden");
});
```

Give position `absolute` to place it over the image

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pdj5xuj6/5/)

Go for @epascarello solution. It is the best.

Comment: Can you teach me how to position it on top of my image and stay at the top left ?

Comment: Did you do any adjustment to my original code to make it work like that ? I'm just curious what did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) accepts two functions:

```
$("#cover-img").hover(function() {
    $("#nav-upload-icon").removeClass("hidden");
}, function() {
    $("#nav-upload-icon").addClass("hidden");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pdj5xuj6/3/)

But obviously [the CSS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30867827/2539720) is better.

Comment: Didn't know that.  Thank-you for teaching me. I'm sure other people like me will learn from this too.

Answer (score 1):

Your almost there. Add a second anonymous function to add the class for `mouseleave`

```
$("#cover-img").hover(function() {
    $("#nav-upload-icon").removeClass("hidden");
}, function() {
    $("#nav-upload-icon").addClass("hidden");
});
```

According to [hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/), you can pass in `handlerIn/handlerOut` which are synonymous with `mouseenter/mouseleave`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pdj5xuj6/4/)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use javascript, wrap a div around the image.

```
<div class="image-wrap">
   <img > <-- your super cool large image
   <img class="upload"> <- your super cool icon and stuff absolutely positioned with 0 transparency
</div>
```

Then in the css you go something like this

```
div.image-wrap:hover img.upload {
    opacity:0.9
}
```

Don't bother with javascript, it's 2015

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved without any JS. Using the adjacent selector you can show the icon when `#cover-img` is hovered on.

```
#cover-img:hover + img {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctafedtq/)